# The teams channel getting spammed with Bot intro message

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have added a bot to a Teams channel.
Each time a new user is added to the Teams channel the bot sends a welcome message inside the channel.
I want this message to be sent to the user personally and not to the whole channel.

Answer (score 0):

You can send message to user on 1:1 using proactive message. When the user added to the team you will receive on member added activity there you can send a message to user personally. Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) for more info and also check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Bots/ProactiveBot.cs#L40)